# How to use 'LIKE' and keep Join values

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables:

```
Category
+-------------+----------+
| category_id | name     |
+-------------+----------+
| 1           | Business |
+-------------+----------+
| 2           | Sport    |
+-------------+----------+
| 3           | Games    |
+-------------+----------+
```

```
News
+----+----------------------+
| id | title                |
+----+----------------------+
| 1  | Bitcoin Price        |
+----+----------------------+
| 2  | Sport                |
+----+----------------------+
| 3  | Electric flying cars |
+----+----------------------+
```

```
CatNews
+---------+--------+
| news_id | cat_id |
+---------+--------+
| 1       | 1      |
+---------+--------+
| 2       | 3      |
+---------+--------+
| 2       | 2      |
+---------+--------+
```

`SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(cat.name) FROM news n JOIN CatNews c ON n.id = c.newsid JOIN category cat ON c.cat_id = cat.category_id GROUP BY n.id;`

**Using this I get a return as**

```
id | title                | news_id | cat_id | name | GROUP_CONCAT(cat.name) 
2  | Electric flying cars |     2   |   3    | Sport | Sport, Games
```

**The problem is when I use this:**

`SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(cat.name) FROM news n JOIN CatNews c ON n.id = c.newsid JOIN category cat ON c.cat_id = cat.category_id AND cat.name LIKE '%Games%' GROUP BY n.id`

**That returns me:**

```
id | title                | news_id | cat_id | name | GROUP_CONCAT(cat.name) 
2  | Electric flying cars |     2   |   3    | Games |   Games
```

**How can I use LIKE find the occurrences but keep the value of GROUP_CONCAT?**

I want to keep [Sport, Games]

Comment: Using `SELECT *, ... GROUP_BY n.id` is bad SQL.https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that you want to return news items that contain "Games".  If so, this is the correct logic:

```
SELECT n.*, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name)
FROM news n JOIN
     CatNews cn
     ON n.id = cn.newsid JOIN
     category c ON cn.cat_id = c.category_id
GROUP BY n.id
HAVING SUM(category_id = 'Games') > 0;
```